# How to use an Azure pipeline to sync a file and subdirectory in one repo with a file and directory in another repo?

Tags: git, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-wiki

So I've got 2 repos, kinda like so:

```
/repoA
   /directoryA
     /fileA
     /subdirectoryA
       ...lots of files in here

/repoB
   /directoryB
   /fileB
   ...lots and lots and lots of other directories and files
```

What I want to do is sync `fileA` with `fileB`, and sync all of the contents of `subdirectoryA` with all the contents of `directoryB` such that any changes I push to `fileA` or anything in `subdirectoryA` will also get pushed by a CI/CD pipeline to the corresponding file or directory in repoB.  I don't care about any of the other files or directories in repoB so I'd rather not have them cluttering up my repoA.

How can I accomplish this?

---

**Context:**  I'm using Azure DevOps, where RepoA is in ProjectA, and RepoB is in ProjectB.  ProjectA is just for my team's use, while ProjectB is for the rest of the company; RepoB is actually the project wiki for ProjectB.  Rather than physically maintaining our documentation in 2 places or having to go to a separate project to update it (a bottleneck like that means it wouldn't get updated, ever), I want to use an Azure Pipeline to automatically push any documentation changes we make in RepoA over to the wiki in RepoB so that everyone's well-informed and happy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your requirement, you need to sync the files in two repos(different project).

There is no out-of-box method could meet your requirements.

To achieve this goal, you could use the Azure Pipeline to do this operation automatically.

Here are the steps:

Step1: Add the extension: [Git Tools for Azure DevOps](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nkdagility.gittasks&ssr=false#overview). And you will get the task: `Git Publish Task` in Pipeline.

Step2: Add Git Publish Task  in Pipeline.

[image]

The Git Repo url sample:

```
https://{UserName}:{PAT(Personal Access Token)}@dev.azure.com/{Organization}/{Project}/_git/{RepoName}
```

Step3: You need to set the [Trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#ci-triggers) in Pipeline.
[image]

You could set the branch and path. When the fileA or the files in the sub folder path are changed, it will trigger this pipeline and the change will be pushed to target repo.

If you don't want to use extension, you could try to use Git command to replace the Git Publish task. But it will be a little more complicated

Comment: This seems like it will be super helpful!  I need a little bit of time to digest it because I'm super new to pipelines and I'm pretty git-challenged, but I wanted to thank you up front for your response.  I will get back to you this week or next to let you know whether it will work or not.  Thank you so much!

Comment: Well, good news (for me because it's less work, lol) - we just learned that you can search across projects!  So we don't need to duplicate our documentation, hooray!  Thus, I'm going to mark your answer as correct and move on to other documentation challenges. Thank you again!